# What output will this app inventor code generate?

Tags: list, if-statement, app-inventor

I am pretty sure this question is going to be flagged but I am in huge confusion from this questions. It is from a sample question paper of my App Development Fundamentals. This is the procedure block: [image]
and this is the part which calls that procedure:
[image]

The questions is:  **What value will be displayed in the label lblOutput after the button has been clicked according to the following code for the button’s Click event**

I know a little about programming and my best guess is that this procedure will sort the numbers in ascending order but I am not sure because of the first **if block**.  It says if item < select item from list (finalList) with index position (which is currently 1). **The finalList is empty**, isn't it? Then wouldn't it show an error? I am confused in that part.

Also, there's an another part of this question:
**What would be a more appropriate name for the procedure (based on its
behaviour)? **

I am guessing the answer would be: ArrangeInAscendingOrder or something like that.

Please someone clarify about that first **if** block.

Thank you.

Comment: your question is off topic and you already know it, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic... Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @Taifun if you read the post again, i have mentioned what i think the answer is

Comment: You will get an error because you don't have anything in the initalize local blocks

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but you might be able to ask in the [MIT google groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/mitappinventortest/app-inventor-extensions).

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure because of the first if block. It says if item < select item from list (finalList) with index position (which is currently 1). The finalList is empty, isn't it? Then wouldn't it show an error?

On the first item, the output list is empty, so the WHILE (1 <= 0)block will
terminate and skip the problematic IF test.